# Как реализовать поддомены с отдельными сайтами внутри Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Возникла ситуация - есть работающий сайт на WP в котором есть страница с примерами лендингов с адресом www.mysite.com/landing-page. Каждый пример landing-page - отдельная веб-страница со своими CSS и JS файлами.
Необходимо встроить страницы так, чтобы получились ссылки вида www.mysite.com/landing-page/1 или www.mysite.com/landing-page/2 и чтобы в примерах landing-page не пришлось переназначать пути файлов.
Есть ли возможность это реализовать в Wordpress?

Comment: Что значит "есть"? И что мешает сделать ещё?

Comment: Имеется ввиду есть действующий сайт, и в нем создана страница для которой нужно решить эту проблему. Новый сайт сделать не нужно, нужно все реализовать на действующем сайте.

Comment: И что мешает  сделать ЕЩЁ хоть 100 страниц? И да, причём тут поддомены вообще?

Comment: Проблема в том, что каждая страница - это отдельный сайт со своими файлами CSS и JS. Если я делаю их страницами, то мне приходится править пути в коде для нормального отображения, что делать очень долго из-за большого количества этих страниц.

Comment: Одна страница - целый сайт?!!!! о ужас. ок ща напишу ответ как сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить в правило .htaccess следующее правило:

```
RewriteBase /landing-page/
```

Должно получиться примерно следующее:

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /landing-page/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /landing-page/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Взято отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196500/configuring-wordpress-htaccess-to-view-subfolders

Comment: Это решение работает, спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

> что каждая страница - это отдельный сайт

Если нужен такой кошмар, то

Вар1. ВП из корня домена убирается (переносится в подкаталог). В корне создаются каталоги на каждый сайт где и устанавливается отдельный  ВП для каждого сайта. В корне домена размешается простой html/php-файл.

Вар2. В корне устанавливается ВП в [сетевой установке](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8) с подкаталогами для сайтов.